# How to join dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join

So I have a data frame like this.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'period':['2021-02'], 'customer':['A'], 'product':['Apple'], 'sales_flag': ['Yes']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'period':['2021-03', '2021-04', '2021-04'], 'customer':['A', 'A', 'A'], 'product':['Banana', 'Apple', 'Tangerine'], 'feedback_flag': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'No']})
```

I want to join the data frame like this.

```
period   customer  product    sales_flag  feedback_flag
'2021-02'    A        Apple         Yes        NULL
'2021-02'    A        Banana        NULL       NULL
'2021-02'    A        Tangerine     NULL       NULL
'2021-03'    A        Apple         NULL       NULL
'2021-03'    A        Banana        NULL       Yes
'2021-03'    A        Tangerine     NULL       NULL
'2021-04'    A        Apple         NULL       Yes
'2021-04'    A        Banana        NULL       NULL
'2021-04'    A        Tangerine     NULL       No
```

My code like this. But it didn't work.

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on = ['period', 'customer', 'product'], how = 'outer')
```

Do you have any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Try append: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try outer [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) followed by a [`groupby apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-apply) to [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas-dataframe-reindex) based on unique products then [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html#pandas-dataframe-ffill) + [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html#pandas-dataframe-bfill) to fill out period and customer:

```py
def reindex_group(g, idx):
    g = g.set_index('product').reindex(idx)
    g[['period', 'customer']] = g[['period', 'customer']].ffill().bfill()
    return g


df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['period', 'customer', 'product'], how='outer')
products = df3['product'].unique()
df3 = (
    df3.groupby(['period', 'customer'], as_index=False)
        .apply(reindex_group, idx=products)
        .reset_index()
        .drop(columns='level_0')
)[['period', 'customer', 'product', 'sales_flag', 'feedback_flag']]
```

`df3`:

```
    period customer    product sales_flag feedback_flag
0  2021-02        A      Apple        Yes           NaN
1  2021-02        A     Banana        NaN           NaN
2  2021-02        A  Tangerine        NaN           NaN
3  2021-03        A      Apple        NaN           NaN
4  2021-03        A     Banana        NaN           Yes
5  2021-03        A  Tangerine        NaN           NaN
6  2021-04        A      Apple        NaN           Yes
7  2021-04        A     Banana        NaN           NaN
8  2021-04        A  Tangerine        NaN            No
```

Comment: It works for single customer, but it doesn't work for multi customer

Comment: so, i have thousand customer, different period, and 27 unique products. If i try to filter one customer, i can use your code. But when i try to use your code will all the data, i got an error like this:```ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis```

Comment: sorry my mistakes. There are still duplicate product on one customer, that's why I got an error. Now, it's running smoothly. Thank you.